# How can I structure my angular app so that I don't end up with one huge controller and view?

Tags: mvc, angularjs

I have an angular app that concentrates most of its functionality around a primary entity that has several satellite entities. The UI for this is effectively one screen, with a few tabs, one for each satellite. There are also some modal dialogs with content for a couple of the satellites that deserve their own subview, produced by clicking on a link in a tab.

The controller for this screen is growing rather large, as it has a set of REST calls for each entity, along with functions to produce and dismiss the various dialogs. All the subviews for the tabs are stuffed into the main screen as well, inside a tab set.

How can I split out these files, giving each tab its own controller and view?

Comment: Are you putting *anything* in your controllers, other than logic that glues the UI to your business layer?

Comment: nope, just the usual: go get the data, display the data, send the data to the server, etc.

Comment: Are you using subviews?  Usually, MVC systems give you some way to compose smaller views into larger ones.

Comment: no, just one big-old view...

Comment: Related: http://jan.varwig.org/archive/how-to-do-nested-views-in-angularjs-hint-dont

Answer (score 0):

Use inline templates to separate views and filters instead of controllers:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/tpl.html">
  Content of the template.
</script>

<a ng-click="currentTpl='/tpl.html'" id="tpl-link">Load inlined template</a>
<div id="tpl-content" ng-include src="currentTpl"></div>
```

Use $templateCache to perform loops, and $cacheFactory to pass data between filters rather than scope.

**References**

- [Angular 1.5 $Filter and $CacheFactory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMReoK4h1qA)
- [Understanding Angular's $templateCache](https://thinkster.io/templatecache-tutorial)
- [AngularJS: API: script](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script)

Answer (score 0):

##### Pattern : Hierarchical routes

The ideal way is to break the UI into hierarchical components, and present them at sub-routes:

```typescript
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      {path: 'tab1' , component: Sattelite1Component },
      {path: 'tab2' , component: Sattelite2Component }
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', redirect: '/tab1'}
]
```

The `MainComponent` can present main data, plus, have a `<router-outlet>` in its HTML to show the current tab/satellite  content. Tab switching is now navigating the router to `/tab1` or `/tab2` etc. The UI and REST calls for satellite entities stay in their own respective components.

##### Pattern: UI overlay as a service

Create an angular service: `PopupService`. Expose a method `showOverlay(ComponentClass, ComponentData)`. Use [Angular CDK](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview) to implement showing any component type with given data as a popup/dialog/modal/whatever. Now you can not only embed custom components via HTML templates, you can also show them floating as an overlay.